# laravel one-to-one unique constrait

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relational-database

I have a one-to-one unidirectional relation.

```
class User extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }
}

class Profile extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

I want to create a user with a single profile:

```
$user = User::firstOrCreate([
    'name' => 'John', 
    'email' => 'john@email.com'
]);
$profile = new Profile([
    'age' => 'age', 
    'sex' => 'sex'
]);
$user->profile()->save($profile);
```

Running this command multiple times creates one user with multiple profiles without a exception/warning that User model will have multiple relations.
How can I create a constraint or ensure that User will have only one profile?

Update:

Because my command can run multiple times, `unique` on `profile_id` will throw an exception which is not ideal in my case. I end up doing something like this:

```
$user = User::firstOrCreate([
    'name' => 'John', 
    'email' => 'john@email.com'
]);
$user->profile()->firstOrCreate([
    'age' => 'age', 
    'sex' => 'sex'
]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can:

1. Set `user_id` as [`unique()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#indexes)
2. Manually check if profile already exists `$user->profile()->isEmpty()`
3. Use [`updateOrCreate()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#other-creation-methods) or [`firstOrCreate()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#other-creation-methods) methods.

Comment: Sorry, maybe in the second step you meant: "$user->profile()->exists()"?